# Prevent Sync Framework from synching deletes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using MS Sync framework to sync records from branch to server. I'm only downloading changes to the main branch server. However, I wanted to prevent the synced records on the main server from being deleted when the records were deleted from the branch server. I want to be able to only upload and update records from the branch to the server and keep them even when deleted on the branch server.

I searched some techniques to do this but the only workable way for me is to disable the delete triggers on the tables on my server database. Are there better approaches for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apart from disabling the delete triggers, you can intercept the changes in the ChangesSelected event and remove the deleted rows so they don't propagate up to the server.

see: [Manipulating the change dataset in Sync Fx](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the link. As I understood, the article focused on the local database cache technique? 

I followed the walkthrough of Sync Framework here:
[link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx

However, I can't seem to figure out how to manipulate the classes used. 
Thank you

Comment: whether its the older Local Database Cache/SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DbServerSyncProvider/SyncAgent or the newer SqlCeSyncProvider/SqlSyncProvider/SyncOrchestrator, there should be a ChangesSelected event...

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I've now managed to manipulate the changes to be uploaded/downloaded based on the article.